# how to add two posts per screen flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a video screen like the picture. on the right side picture showing my implementation so far. how can I create video screen like half of the screen and one after the other as left UI below. (two videos per screen). appriciate your help on this. I haveadded my code for your refernce

[image]  [image]

post_template.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants/button.dart';


class PostTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final String username;
  final String videoDescription;
  final String numberOfLikes;
  final String numberOfComments;
  final String numberOfShares;
  final userPost;

  PostTemplate({
    required this.username,
    required this.videoDescription,
    required this.numberOfLikes,
    required this.numberOfComments,
    required this.numberOfShares,
    required this.userPost,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // user post (at the very back)
          userPost,

          // user name and caption
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment(-1, 1),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text('@' + username,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: videoDescription,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: ' #live #lalaive',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // buttons
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment(1, 1),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  MyButton(
                    icon: Icons.people,
                    number: numberOfComments,

                  ),
                  MyButton(
                    icon: Icons.thumb_up,
                    number: numberOfLikes,
                  ),
                  MyButton(
                    icon: Icons.share,
                    number: numberOfShares,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

video_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lala_live/screens/post_template.dart';

class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
  final _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: _controller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          MyPost1(),
          MyPost2(),
          MyPost3(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPost1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PostTemplate(
        username: 'amandasharma',
        videoDescription: 'Free your mind',
        numberOfLikes: '1.2M',
        numberOfComments: '1232',
        numberOfShares: '122',
        userPost: Container(
          //color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage("asset/images/girl.jpeg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

class MyPost2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PostTemplate(
      username: 'zuckerberg',
      videoDescription: 'reels for days',
      numberOfLikes: '1.2M',
      numberOfComments: '232',
      numberOfShares: '122',
      userPost: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage("asset/images/nature.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPost3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PostTemplate(
      username: 'randomUser',
      videoDescription: 'Free your mind',
      numberOfLikes: '1.2B',
      numberOfComments: '232',
      numberOfShares: '122',
      userPost: Container(
        color: Colors.blue[300],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for `MyPost3()` you can wrap the containers in a column and use the Expanded widget.

```
class MyPost3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPost3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PostTemplate(
      username: 'randomUser',
      videoDescription: 'Free your mind',
      numberOfLikes: '1.2B',
      numberOfComments: '232',
      numberOfShares: '122',
      userPost: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue[300],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red[300],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is where you want the video widgets to appear ,

```
   // user post (at the very back)
          userPost,
```

You can put the widgets in a column and use Expandable to give them size, i.e flex 2 for each to split screen halfway.

```
Column -
       - Expanded( flex:2, child:video1
       - Expanded( flex:2, child:video2
```

Comment: please check my videoscren.dart.. under page view I have added like this         children: [
          MyPost1(),
          MyPost2(),
          MyPost3(),
        ],  how should I want to change this

Comment: Seems like a post has two videos, in this case , `PostTemplate` should handle the video widgets , in your `videoscren.dart` you just provide the data

Comment: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. << getting this error... I have covered my post1, post2, post3 widget as you said sir

Answer (score 0):

On `MyPost3()`:

```
return PostTemplate(
    username: 'randomUser',
    videoDescription: 'Free your mind',
    numberOfLikes: '1.2B',
    numberOfComments: '232',
    numberOfShares: '122',
    userPost: SafeArea(
      child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ))
      ]),
    ));
```

You can use an `Expanded()` to take as much space you can, surrounded by a `SafeArea()` to ensure your screens don't overlap with your status bar leaving the possibility of an overflow.